# Set symfony env value as path

Tags: symfony4

I am trying to set an env variable as path. I have a file `credentials.json` under `config` folder in Symfony4.

I need to set an env param like `CREDENTIALS_PATH=config/credentials.json` in `.env` file, but I got `errors`. It seems like the path is not recognized like that.

Does someone know how to set this?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot double quotes `CREDENTIALS_PATH="config/credentials.json"`

Comment: Nope, it's not that :(

Comment: What's the error?